# Drupal rendering incomplete views

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I got tapped to do some quick maintenance on a recently migrated Drupal site.  I'm pretty new to Drupal, so hopefully the problem is something that more experienced guys will figure out quick.

Behavior is as follows. The public content works fine as far as I can tell.  When I go to login, the login form renders correctly, but when I post the form w/ my credentials, I get back a blank page (not a 404; looks like a 200 to the /user URL, but all the gets rendered is empty Head and body tags).  If i refresh the page, I get the content of my profile view, but none of the site chrome or CSS.  Note that this is not an issue on the site it was migrated from, so it seems like something wasn't copied over correctly.  The site's not public, so I can't provide a URL, sorry!

Comment: Sounds like there is a PHP error somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird, some other guy gave me a link in an answer, which led to me solving the problem, but when I came back to give him credit, his answer was deleted.  Basically I went here:

http://drupal.org/node/158043

To find out how to enable error reporting, then found out it was a problem w/ the PHP version's handling of a date function from here:

http://drupal.org/node/201470